# On Equeum, how to specify a list of tokens (or coins) using EQL

Tags: list, equeum, eql

In EQL, you can use two different lines for more than one asset

```
1. BTC.priceVolumeFactor -> avgSimple(30)    
2. ETH.priceVolumeFactor -> avgSimple(30)
```

How can you do this in one line?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing so:

```
1.[BTC.priceVolumeFactor, ETH.priceVolumeFactor] ->  avgSimple(60)
```

or

```
2. [BTC, ETH].priceVolumeFactor ->  avgSimple(60)
```

In either case, the assets are charted in the same pane.